# How do I automatically rename and move movies?

Tags: video, automation, rename

I'm looking for some software which will take a video file, work out the correct name of the film, rename it and then move it to another drive on my computer inside a folder with the same name. So for example, "**Saw III.avi**" would get renamed and moved to "**D:\Movies\Saw III (2006)\Saw III (2006).avi**".

I've tried [TheRenamer](http://www.therenamer.com), but to be honest the movie detection is pretty rubbish. For example, it wanted to rename all three files ("Saw II.avi", "Saw III.avi" and "Saw IV.avi") to the same thing ("IMDB Boards Saw 3D.avi"). Not only was it wrong, but it managed to pick a film that isn't even out on DVD yet! This isn't a single hiccup, almost every film I've bought, ripped and then thrown at it has been met with completely the wrong film title.

Does anyone have any recommendations for software which can do what I'm looking for? It needs to work on Windows and should be possible to run as a scheduled task without any interaction needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a look at [MediaRenamer](http://code.google.com/p/mediarenamer/).

Comment: Whilst I've marked this as the best answer it is worth noting that this isn't perfect. It has almost no documentation and so it's impossible to tell whether it can be run as a scheduled task. Its matching isn't as good as TheRenamer when the name of the file contains a lot of extra rubbish but at least it correctly recognises the films I listed in my question. In addition, it is only able to move the film to another folder and cannot create a sub-folder - therefore you cannot the film to "Saw II (2007)\Saw II (2007).avi".